# How to compress gif effectively to reduce size?

Tags: ffmpeg, compression, imagemagick, gif, animated-gif

We use gifs for our blog extensively. We used to embed tenor nano gifs(90px height maintaining aspect ratio, used for GIF previews and shares on mobile) in it. Now we wanted to create our own gifs and are using the following command to convert mp4 to gif while maintaining the properties of tenor's nano gif. using ffmpeg version 4.1.4

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v]fps=10,scale=-1:90:flags=lanczos,split [a][b];[a] palettegen [p];[b][p] paletteuse" -y output.gif
```

But we observed a huge difference in size between the gif we created and the one created using tenor.

[Original MP4] - 845KB

[Tenor Nano gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uox30.gif) - 42KB

[ffmpeg gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JUhGN.gif) - 106KB

We even tried changing dithering algorithm to further reduce size but it ended up adding noise and damaged the gif quality.

```
paletteuse=dither=bayer:bayer_scale=5:diff_mode=rectangle
```

We tried tweaking colour quantization in gifsicle as well but it was of no use

```
gifsicle --resize _x90 --colors 256 --color-method diversity --dither=ordered --resize-method sample input.gif > output.gif
```

Are we missing anything?